# Capistrano is complaining

Tags: capistrano

Hi im trying to deploy a script, 
after writting it

I ran a `cap deploy:check`

I get this error

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/sshkit-1.3.0/lib/sshkit.rb:32: undefined method `require_relative' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-3.1.0/lib/capistrano/all.rb:2
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-3.1.0/bin/cap:2
from /usr/local/bin/cap:19:in `load'
from /usr/local/bin/cap:19
```

I understand that, sshkit is not installed and required in my deploy.rb
Or is this a versioning problem?.
Im running ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sshkit` gem is designed to run on Ruby 1.9+, and you are running Ruby 1.8.